# Every embedding of $K$ extends to exactly $[L:K]$ embeddings of $L$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble with a line of the proof of the following fact in Marcus's Number Fields: Every embedding of $K$ extends to exactly $[L:K]$ embeddings of $L$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

(By Induction on $[L:K]$) This is trivial if $[L:K]=1$. So suppose otherwise. Let $\sigma$ be an embedding of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Take any $\alpha\in L-K$ and let $f$ be the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $K$. Let $g$ be the polynomial obtained from $f$ by applying $\sigma$ to all the coefficients. Then $g$ is irreducible over the field $\sigma K$.

My question is: why is $g$ irreducible over the field $\sigma K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $f$, being the minimal polynomial of a field element, is irreducible, and therefore so is its image under the embedding $\sigma$ over the embedded copy of $K$.